# Laravel event attendees eloquent vs collections

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I have a situation where users can select from one of a range of event dates, but only events where the current number of attendees does not exceed a set number of spaces available per event.

Schema

```
        Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->datetime('occurs_at');
            $table->smallInteger('spaces_available')->unsigned()->default('8');
        });
```

App\Event

```
    public function attendees ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

The query:

```
                \App\Event::withCount('attendees')
                    ->get()
                    ->filter(function ($event) {
                        return ($event->spaces_available - $event->attendees_count) > 0;
                    });
```

Just wondering how the filter() bit on the collection could be done in the Eloquent query instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this manually using the `whereRaw()` method in Eloquent:

```php
$availableEvents = Event::query()
    ->whereRaw('spaces_available - (select count(*) from users where event_id = events.id) > 0')
    ->get();
```

And, of course, you could add a scope for this to your `Event` model:

```php
class Event extends Model
{
    public function attendees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    public function scopeStillAvailable($query)
    {
        $query->whereRaw('spaces_available - (select count(*) from users where event_id = events.id) > 0');
    }
}
```

And now you can do this:

```php
$availableEvents = Event::stillAvailable()->get();
```